# Regex to validate particular url

Tags: angularjs, validation

I am using angularjs. I want to use validation for my url field. I am a beginner in regex expressions. I want that the url should starting with 'https' or 'http' and followed by a string(this string can be a string or ip). For E.g https://localhost or http://100.100.100.100 should be valid and ftp://localhost should be invalid as it is starting with ftp.

I am using ng-pattern to validate this field. What regex expression should i use? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Where are the good old days, where you face a problem, think about it, read manuals and documentation, try several things, fail, try several other things, ask a friend, try even harder and finally come up with a solution you are more proud of than anything else in the world?

Comment: Did you manage to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The following regexp should do it, or at least be a good start:

```
https?:\/\/[0-9A-z.]+
```

**What it does:**

- **http** matches the characters http literally (case sensitive)
- **s?** matches the character s literally (case sensitive)

  - **?** Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible
- **:** matches the character : literally (case sensitive)
- **/** matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
- **/** matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
- **[0-9A-z.]+** Match any character present in the lists (0-9 = all numbers from 0 to 9, A-z = all letters case insensitive, . = matches also the . character)

  - **+** Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible

By the way this is simple enought and you could have figured it out by yourself. Googling *url regex* gives tons of other possible solutions.

If you are interested in trying out your regexs, this website will be really useful to you: **[regex101](https://regex101.com/)**